# Any possible way for support the all kinds of fonts in all browser?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm beginner in HTML.

In browser not supported the all kind of fonts. Like old version of the mozila not supported the some kind of fonts. what are the fonts are supported in all kinds of browser.

I know in this case uses the `font-family`. For example I used the font family is:

```
{
    font-family:cambria,Helvetica,monospace;
}
```

I create the pages and visual effect is done in my browser. In my browser support the first font is the `cambria`. Perhaps i display the page in the other system which support the `Helvetica` fonts.

My problem is I design the page for `cambria` fonts like `font-size , line-height and etc`
But in other system it will changes for `Helvetica` font family, so i don't get what i expect.

How can i manage the this kind of problem and what are fonts are supported in all kind of browser include the very old version browser also.?

Comment: down voter add comment

Comment: A simple google search will get you all web-safe fonts

Comment: @WhiteNightFury Thank you for saying this. I search the google for safe fonts but that the safe fonts are not suited for me. So i uses the another fonts. I mean any possible way for uses any fonts in all browser.

Comment: Ah, well in that case http://bit.ly/1vfkYx9

Comment: check out google fonts: http://www.google.com/fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@font-face CSS will bring in fonts for you have a look [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts)

```css
@font-face {
     font-family: TheFontName;
     src: url(www.googletheFont.woff);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you I expect this kind of answer.

Answer (score 0):

use generic fonts that work in all browsers/os like times, open sans etc.
or better use solutions like webfonts, font-face, google fonts, adobe typekit for custom fonts